# How to filter out a Sub Array from a Parent Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, element

I got an Array `a = [1,2,3,4,5]` and an Array `b = [1,3]` which contains some elements of `a`. So it is a kind of a sub array of `a`.

In this for loop below, I can use the elements of `b` to "do smething". Now, how can I interact in the same loop with the elements of `a` that are not a part `b`? That means `2, 4 and 5` from `a`? How to filter them out?

```
function action (){
for (var i=0; i<b.length; i++) {

      b[i].x = "do something";


  }
```

Thanks so much"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript array difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `filter()` function combined with the `includes()` function to filter the list:

```
const diff = a.filter(i => !b.includes(i));
```

`diff` will contain just the elements in `a` that aren't in `b`.

This is called a *difference* between the arrays. There are also a lot of libraries that will include a some sort of `diff` function for arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` on your `a` array to get a new list of elements not contained:

```
a.filter(item => !b.includes(item)).forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for this : `a.filter((element) => !b.includes(element))`

#### Sample

```js
const a = [1,2,3,4,5];
const b = [1,3]

const elements_in_a_not_in_b = a.filter((element) => !b.includes(element))

console.log(
  elements_in_a_not_in_b
)
```